# Авто очистка таблицы в MySQL

Tags: phpmyadmin, php, mysql

Здравствуйте! У меня вопрос: как сделать так, что если в таблице messages больше 25 записей то записи удаляются (таблица остается!). Помогите.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$res = mysql_query('select count(*) as `amount` from `messages`');
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
if($row['amount']>25){
mysql_query('TRUNCATE TABLE `messages`');
}
```

Как-то так.
Выполнять по крону или вручную. Как удобнее.

Comment: Спасибо! Очень помогло!